# How to apply groupby in pandas to work out customer-specific queries over time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got some transaction data over time and I'm trying to apply a groupby in Pandas so I can establish the average revenue spent, average number of transactions by customers by year but can't work out how to do it in Pandas.

The data looks like this:

```
CustomerID  Year Revenue
123         2018 2000
126         2019 157
123         2019 563
674         2018 320
```

I've tried various groupbys such as:

```
df.groupby(["CustomerID", "Year"]).median()
```

But that just returns a massive dataframe.

Comment: What is your expected output? Why your groupby does not work?

Comment: Formatting of that groupby query is wrong. Should be `df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'Year']).median()`

Comment: @ChrisA Oops, I'll update it. Typo

Comment: @villoro It doesn't work because although it aggregates by customer, it doesn't aggregate by year. I realised I had to run two groupby functions in one line. Seems a bit hacky, though.

Answer (score 0):

I realise it has to be a nested groupby. For instance to find out the number of customers in a year:

groupby(['CustomerID', 'Year']).count().groupby("Year").count()

I'm sure there is a more elegant approach, mind.